# iTunes on Windows Refuses to Upgrade

Tags: windows, upgrade, quicktime, itunes

I've been having a problem when trying to upgrade iTunes on Windows (7 x64). Every time I try to upgrade it, I get the error message:

> QuickTime was not found.
>
> QuickTime is required to run iTunes. Please uninstall iTunes, then install iTunes again.

Wanting to upgrade to 9.2 to get iOS4, I obliterated anything to do with Apple from my machine and reinstalled successfully, but this error comes back time and time again.

I recently found that [I am not the only one suffering from this](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2010/08/16/frustration-thy-name-is-apple.aspx).

Is there a way to solve this issue or am I doomed to stay like this forever?

Comment: I've had the same issue here...

Comment: Are you sure quicktime is actually installed- and is installed where iTunes thinks it should be?

Comment: @Cameron - It's installed in the same place the original iTunes installation installed it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the installer expects Quicktime to be there but when it looks it can't find it.

Have you tried removing any registry entries to do with Quicktime and retrying the install?

Comment: Yes, and I was successful upgrading, but it doesn't make sense that this issue would return every time I wanted to upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. iTunes on Windows 7, installed with default configuration months ago. After that I have upgraded it several times successfully, again with default settings. Now the latest iTunes upgrade offered by Apple Software Updater suddenly fails with "QuickTime required" error. iTunes and QuickTime Player fully working, only upgrading to latest version fails.

Comment: Removed QuickTime and reinstalled it from the media downloaded @ http://apple.com/quicktime/download
. Installed iTunes as upgrade (on top of the existing) from the media downloaded @ http://appldnld.apple.com/iTunes10/041-2074.20110822.GbpP5/iTunes64Setup.exe
. iTunes is now working and the latest version. Let's hope that the normal updater works when the next update is released.